# Address of Gitlab repository on VPS

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I installed GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.5.4-ee in my VPS (centos 7) and create some project, the URL of one of them for clone is :

git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:root/ir-module-software.git

Where can i find project repository?

I used following command :

```
find / -name ir-module-software.git
```

but no thing was find.

I saw `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` directory  but no proper thing was found (It is no empty).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default repositories are hashed and stored on `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed`, for disable `hash`, go to `admin_area->setting->repository->Repository storage` and remove tick of `Use hashed storage`

Answer (score 0):

`/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` is the correct location of your repository. Gitlab (and git) stores your repository on the server in the form of a "bare" repository.

> A bare Git repository is typically used as a Remote Repository that is
>   sharing a repository among several different people. You don't do work
>   right inside the remote repository so there's no Working Tree (the
>   files in your project that you edit), just bare repository data.

Think of it as the contents of your `.git` folder when you clone it locally.

Comment: I know this concept, but there isn't  any "*.git" folder in "..../repositories" directory.Only there is two folders " +gitaly   @hashed" in "..../repositories" directory.I searched my repository name through "find" command but nothing is found.